# How to sculpt seperately?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

[image]

I tried sculpting on the original model, but that it giving weird blur effect around the design. As per the video, the tutor created/ sculpted the design separately. How is that possible?

Comment: No idea since we can't read your mind to find out what video you're watching!

Comment: I have attached screen shot. If anyone can understand please let me know

Comment: Doesn't help as you still haven't said what video it's come from!

Comment: To me, it doesn't look like the design is separated from the teapot. You can sculpt such a design with an inverted mask or alpha brushes. Or maybe a displacement modifier.